# Spring Security AuthenticationException persistent?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Security on a project, and am implementing a login form with it.  I've run into a sort of strange behaviour, which I wouldn't expect, and I was wondering if there is a way to avoid it.

When there is an authentication error on the login form, I have a method in my controller to handle it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/failed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginFailurePage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authExClass = "";
    AuthenticationException authEx = (AuthenticationException) request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

    if (authEx != null) {
      authExClass = authEx.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
    model.addAttribute("authExClass", authExClass);
    return LOGIN_PAGE;
  }
```

This works initially, allowing me to display an error when an authentication error occurs.  However, if I refresh the page, I would expect that the AuthenticationException would no longer be attached to the session, and thus I wouldn't display an error to the user.  However, it seems that the exception persists beyond a refresh.  Do I have an incorrect assumption?  Should I not be using my request object this way?

Thanks!
idbentley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, does any code clear the `AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION` from the Session? Spring Security may not automatically clear this from the session until an another authorization attempt is successful - I think you are assuming that this session attribute is automatically removed.

You may want to clear this attribute from the session yourself to not display it again.